# Match up until a certain set of character with regex

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and i am struggling to match a certain pattern.

There is an existing regex expression that i am trying to complete in other to expand the matched string

```
Kg)\\n\\n\\w\*\\s(.*)\\s\\d*\\s\\S\*\\
```

This is my text, in bold is the character currently matched :

N°OP Adresse de Livraison Nb Colis Poids (**Kg)**

**Y007817281 ZACECDO ZAC & CE. KG 7260540 / 0006421158 1 9.635**
MANYA GER ZER 5
Germany
89081 ULM DE Germany
0469839809,
TOTAL POUR : Nbre O.P. Nbre COLIS POIDS TOTAL (Kg)
1 1 9.64

The format of this text is always the same but some values can change. I would like to expand the matched string in order to check if the string contains "ulm" later on in my code and ulm isn't currently contained.

I would like to expand the regex expression to match up until `DE Germany` because this will always be in format `XX COUNTRY`, however this text

```
MANYA GER ZER 5
Germany
89081 ULM
```

changes often and can be any mix of digits and words

I hope it's clear. How can I achieve this please?

I tried this `Kg\\)\\n\\n\\w\*\\s(.\*\\n\\.\*\\s\\N\*\\n\\N\*\\n\[0-9\]+)\\s` but i'm not sure it's robust nor how many words there could be between the last digits `\[0-9\]+` (`89081` in the texy)  and the two letters (`DE`) in the text

Comment: Use `.*` or `.*?` to match unspecified text in the middle.

Comment: will the end of the string ("DE Germany 0469839809, TOTAL POUR : Nbre O.P. Nbre COLIS POIDS TOTAL (Kg) 1 1 9.64") always be of the same structure?